# unfortunately myapp has stopped working with multiple activities

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

My application contain 5 activities with backgrounds images and when I try to run it .
My application stopped in third activity and shows the error "unfortunately, myapp has stopped" I'm using android studio

logcat :

```
08-23 05:28:10.598 3820-3820/com.example.apollo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.example.apollo.myapplication, PID: 3820
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.apollo.myapplication/com.example.apollo.myapplication.Main3Activity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                             Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                                at com.example.apollo.myapplication.Main3Activity.onCreate(Main3Activity.java:13)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                at com.example.apollo.myapplication.Main3Activity.onCreate(Main3Activity.java:13) 
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 43877388 byte allocation with 11648040 free bytes and 11MB until OOM
                                                                                at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                                at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                                at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
                                                                                at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
                                                                                at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:988)
                                                                                at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2474)
                                                                                at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
                                                                                at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
                                                                                at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3737)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:497)
                                                                                at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:248)
                                                                                at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:244)
                                                                                at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:240)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                at com.example.apollo.myapplication.Main3Activity.onCreate(Main3Activity.java:13) 
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: this is surely memory issue try to release memory by setting your background images to 0 call `view.setBackgroundResource(0)` when you finish any activity

Comment: did you mean:  Intent intent = new Intent(this,Main2Activity.class);

        startActivity(intent);
        view.setBackgroundResource(0);

Comment: no, suppose you have 2 activities(A,B). if you start B from A and when you start activity B and you are finishing Activity A after you call intent for A. this will call onDestroy() of Activity A. you have to remove background of each and every view in onDestroy() method Activity A. and that will release some memory for activity B. i hope you understood it well.

Comment: yes i understood clearly your explanation. please  for completing your answer ,  last question for example i want to start activity B .what i should write in the activity A java in methods on Create on Start on Stop to move to Activity B & thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple Activities with so many Images , You will have this error in most cases. 
To eliminate this type of errors you should always release memory by removing background.

Android generates Bitmap for every Image that you used in your activity , and bitmaps occupies way much memory (Generated bitmap size = height * width * 8). and android assign only 16Mb heap to an application. you can use large heap but it does not guaranty that your application will not crash again.

android does not release images that you have used in activity after destroying it. so it will be always there in memory if you don't really use that. so you have to do that manually with code.
simply you can remove that background for each and every view as soon as you finish any activity in `onDestroy()` method or you can remove background when one activity pauses in `onStop()` method and re-assign images in `onStart()` method.

you can call `view.setBackgroundResource(0)` to remove background resource from that view. and `view.setImageResource(0)` to remove Image Resource from that view.

another option is generate image bitmaps by yourself , scale your bitmaps according to available memory. but i think your problem will be solved if you release your image resource.

Comment: prashant, did you mean   Activity life cycle ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use android:largeHeap="true" to have more memory

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestApplication_largeHeap